# Using regex and subset to extract a subset of a data frame

Tags: regex, r, subset

I have ONE **column** inside a dataframe that contains different kinds of text within it, for example as follows:

```
Column A                 Column B               Column C
Kuala Lumpur 2 new        7                      A
old Jakarta 3             6                      C
7 Hong Kong               3                      A
Jakarta new 22            2                      B
```

My goal is to extract ALL **rows** of the dataframe corresponding to where the word 'Jakarta' is somewhere in the aforementioned column. I imagine that regex is capable of finding the word, but not sure how one could combine this to extract all the info via subset. Note that my sheet is very large, so would prefer to use a command like subset rather than a loop if possible. The desired output would be:

```
Column A                 Column B               Column C
old Jakarta 3             6                      C
Jakarta new 22            2                      B
```

Many thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `grepl`

***DATA***

```
df <- data.frame(ColumnA=c("Kuala Lumpur 2 new", "old Jakarta 3", "7 Hong Kong", "Jakarta new 22"),
             Columnb=c(7, 6, 3, 2), Columnc=c("A", "C", "A", "B"))
```

***Code***

```
df[grepl("Jakarta ", df$ColumnA), ]
```

Comment: Or a bit faster: `df[stringi::stri_detect_fixed(df$ColumnA, "Jakarta"), ]`

Comment: Thanks guys! Great stuff. Appreciated